# Using Sumproduct function that divides and has an array as an exponent

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to replicate the following sumproduct formula in vba and I keep getting an error message.

Excel Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($CN8:$CN367/(1+18/2)^($CV$8:$CV$367*2))
```

VBA code:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct("CN8:CN367" / (1 + 18 / 200) ^ ("CV8:CV367" * 2))
```

Comment: `"CN8:CN367"` should be `Range("CN8:CN367")` same with the other range

Comment: I changed it to the following and still get Run-Time error '13'   
                            Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Range("CN8:CN367") / (1 + 18 / 200) ^ (Range("CV8:CV367") * 2))

Comment: Where is the VBA? Is it in Excel or have you set a reference to Excel in another Office product?

Comment: The VBA is in Excel

Comment: I would use `Worksheet("sheetname").Evaluate("YourFormula")`

Comment: VBA doesn't like to use WorksheetFunction.SumProduct. You have to fool the compiler by using Evaluate on a text string representing your formula.